# Concatenate c(Var1,Var2) Outputs a List Not a Vector

Tags: vector, concatenation

I have a data frame with a variable that I would like to extract into a vector as input to a function that requires a vector. The data frame is EuroRF
Here is the top row of the data frame:

```
Country                Region  Capital  `Capital + Country`              Longitude Latitude
  <chr>                  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>                                <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Albania                Eastern Tirana   Tirana, Albania                       19.8     41.3
```

I execute the following:
`Pt1 <- c (EuroRF[1,5], EuroRF[1,6])`

Then I execute `typeof(Pt1)` whuch gives me

```
[1] "list"
```

I expected a vector.
The function will not take Pt1 because it is a list.
Could someone explain this behavior and how do I put the data into a vector?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Pt1 is a list instead of a vector is because you used the comma operator to select the subset of the data frame. When you use the comma operator to subset a data frame, the result is a data frame, which is essentially a list of vectors (one vector per column).

To extract a vector from a data frame, you can use the [[]] operator instead of the [ , ] operator. Here's how you can modify your code to extract a vector:

```
Pt1 <- c(my_data[[5]], my_data[[6]])
```

This code uses the double brackets to select the 5th and 6th columns of the data frame as separate vectors, and then concatenates them into a single vector using the c() function.

Now, when you run typeof(Pt1), you should get:

```
[1] "double"
```

indicating that Pt1 is now a numeric vector, which can be used as input to your function.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn’t attentive to the use of the comma.